# Setting SDLmain.lib and other SDL features to link properly

Tags: linker, sdl, visual-studio-2012

I'm not a big C++ coder, I don't like the language myself but I know that even if I just want to screw around I need to try and force myself to get this working.

Anyway, my problem is that I'm trying to get the 64 bit SDL libs to get linked up so I can go on my way with making stuff, but after setting up a project and adding the developer DLLs to my VC folder (I was being guided by a friend since again, not a big C++ coder) which i have shown here.
[image: Directory]
[image: Dir2]

Anyway, when I try to link them in VS2012 it just gives me a generic error shown below
[image: linkerror]

No matter what i name it, if it is SDLmain.lib or Cats.lib it just gives me that error.

I pretty much have no idea how to get around this, most SDL tutorials use different editors/compilers or use an older version of VS which lets you manually link them from external folders.

Have I put it in the wrong directory or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your error means that VS do not "**FIND**" the file.

Try to set the full path to the lib, something like `"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\SDLmain.lib"`

If it solves the error, the local VS directory might be wrong.